# Combining "dddd" with "long date" in VBA gives strange result

Tags: excel, vba

Why does the below code give such a strange result? I know I can chance the format to `"dddd d mmmm yyyy"`, but I just want to know the reason behind this ?bug?:

```
?format(#2/3/2014#,"dddd" & "long date")
```

Results in

```
Mondaylo0g 3ate
```

Comment: This is not a bug; there is no formatting string as "long date", you should create your long date formatting manually such as "dd.mm.yyyy dddd" etc.

Comment: @HakanERDOGAN yes there is `? format(#2/3/2014#,"long date")` returns `Monday, February 3, 2014`

Comment: Not a bug but you are confusing the overhead that sees 'long date' as a synonym for the system's regional long date setting (see your control panel, system for more) by prefixing dddd.

Comment: Scott, your code ? format(#2/3/2014#,"long date") returns:
03 February 2014. I want indeed Monday in front of it, so instead of typing the long format "dddd d mmmm yyyy", I thought I just do a simple concatenation with "long date" but that doesn't seem to work. I am not interested in the solution, because I know that already, I just want to know why VBA can't handle this - in my opinion - simple concatenation.

Comment: I got it now, "Long Date" works as a kind of Constant, not a standard formatting string, so you may not change it. To achieve what you need, you may first create a "dddd" formatted variable, and a "Long Date" formatted one and concatenate them afterwards.

Comment: Try this `?format(#2/3/2014#,"herzelenberg")`

Comment: @JohnHorzelenberg must be a local setting thing,  [This is my output](https://imgur.com/a/Ar4a6Fr)

Comment: Thanks Hakan, that answers my question. Thanks to all of you for contributing. Guess I have to stick to "dddd d mmmm yyyy". :-)

Comment: Concatenating the two strings inside the function is asking for `?format(#2/3/2014#,"ddddlong date")` to concatenate them surely you'd do something like: `?format(#2/3/2014#,"dddd") & " " & ?format(#2/3/2014#,"long date")`

Comment: it should be `Format(#2/3/2014# , "dddd") & "long date"` returns Monday long date